# How to create project in node.js using html5 and mysql?

Tags: node.js

I want to include my another js file and one html file(dashboard.html).How it will possible?

```
var file = require('display.js'),    
var http = require('http'),    
fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./dashboard.html',file, function (err, html) {    
if (err) {    
    throw err;    
}  
http.createServer(function(request, response) {      
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(html);       
        response.end();      
}).listen(9236);    
});
```

Please suggest me proper way to do this thing?

Comment: `display.js` is the one which you created?

Answer (score 0):

In `nodejs` if you want to add your own `libraries/js`.

use this

```
var file = require('./display.js'),  // or the path to file it will load file from path
```

instead of

```
var file = require('display.js'), // here it will search in node_modules filder
```

You should know how `node` look for modules. I'm adding what I know.

If you will require some `./somefolder/somefile.js` it will search for the path `./somefolder/somefile.js` and load that file.

If you will add `'somefile.js` it will search for the librery `somefile.js` to `node_modules` folder in your root directory. If it won't get the file there it will go to `global` path of `node_modules`.

If it didn't get that file in global `node_modules` also, it throws an error

```
Cannot find module <file.js>
```

Anyone can improve my answer if anything I missed.

Comment: Thanks for reply,  But my js file is not display only html file is display in webpage?